# UIScrollView overlapping popping UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I've got a `UIScrollView` with multiple pages, each containing a `UITableViewController` (similar to the Reminders-App).
Clicking a cell in each of these `UITableViewControllers` cause a `DetailViewController` to be pushed.

However, when the `DetailViewController` gets popped, it immediately disappears behind the `UIScrollView`, instead of sliding away smoothly. I can see the next page of the `UIScrollView` sliding away, but when the `DetailViewController` is pushed from the last page, the transition looks fine because there is no content on the `UIScrollView` that could overlap the dismissed `DetailViewController`.

**Edit**

This is how I create the view controller hierarchy (simplified):

ScheduleViewController.m:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    // ... 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        MyTableViewController *myTableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTableView" bundle:nil];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:myTableViewController];
        [self addChildViewController:myTableViewController];
        [myTableViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
```

And here is 
`tableView:didSelectCellAtIndexPath:` in `MyTableViewController`:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        // ... 
        [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        DetailViewController* detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

    }
}
```

What could I be doing wrong here? Are there any workarounds to this behavior?

Comment: Is the superview for your `UIScrollView` set to `clipToBounds` (the option is called `Clip Subviews` in the interface builder)? As you noticed, it appears that the `UIScrollView` is probably running off its superview, since it is so much larger, and that is causing your animation to look bad. Clipping it should keep that from happening, but my experience with scroll views is limited.

Comment: *facepalm* that's exactly what the issue was - too much coding today. Thanks! If you add your comment as an answer, I will mark it as accepted and upvote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The superview for your `UIScrollView` needs to have `clipsToBounds` set to TRUE (the option is called `Clip Subviews` in the interface builder, if you creating your view that way.) As you noticed, it appears that the `UIScrollView` is probably running off its superview, since it is so much larger, and that is causing your animation to look bad. Clipping it will keep that from happening.